# Destructure dashed aria props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct syntax or is it even possible to destructure dashed props like `aria-label`?

I have tried simply destructuring it

```
const { destination, label, aria-label, ...blockProps } = props;
```

but TypeScript complains about

> TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

Wrapping `aria-label` in quotes like when we're defining props for example...

```
const { destination, label, 'aria-label', ...blockProps } = props;
```

results in

> ESLint: Parsing error: ':' expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { destination, label, 'aria-label': ariaLabel, ...blockProps } = props;
```

Your variable will be `ariaLabel`